# warning:Failed to open stream and warning:unable to move in move_upload_file()

Tags: php

HTML file:

```
<input type="file" name="photo" size="300" accept="image/*" id="photo"/>
```

PHP part:

```
if ( move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['photo'] ['tmp_name'], 
       "C:\xampp\htdocs\ShowYourTalent/{$_FILES['photo'] ['name']}"))
```

When i run this code, i get following errors:

**Warning:** move_uploaded_file(C: mpp\htdocs\ShowYourTalent/1.gif): failed to open stream: Invalid argument

**Warning:** move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpDE21.tmp' to 'C: mpp\htdocs\syt/1.gif'

Comment: disha you have problem in the query, as i read your comment below, it suggest to me that you are echo the result without fetching it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using double quotes and backslashes in the path name. This makes PHP interpreting the sequence:

```
"\xa"
```

.. the start of `xampp`, as the hexadecimal representation `xA` (10 in decimal). The character `10` represents a newline in ASCII which is not valid in a Windows path name. That's why you are getting the warnings.

**Solution**:

Use forward slashes, PHP will translate them to proper Windows paths:

```
if ( move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['photo'] ['tmp_name'], 
       "C:/xampp/htdocs/ShowYourTalent/{$_FILES['photo'] ['name']}"))
```

Comment: The warning has been solved by this..It also shows that data inserted successfully.. But, it is not displaying in database table.(phpmyadmin). It shows following message: The file has been successfully uploaded
Database Found Resource id #3
Data Inserted Successfully

Comment: You would need to create a separate question for that problem. As it is not related to the upload but to the database code.